# Как получить часовой пояс текущей ОС с помощью inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Как в inno setup получить текущий часовой пояс?

Answer (score 0):

Зону можно посмотреть в реестре: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`.

У меня под рукой сейчас нет windows, но думаю, что код будет приблизительно таким:

```
function GetTZ(Default: String): String;
  {function to get time zone}
  var ResultStr: String;
  begin
    Result:='{app}';
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM,'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control','TimeZoneInformation',ResultStr) 
    then
       Result:=ResultStr
    end;
  end;
```

Можно ещё запустить `TZUTIL.exe` с параметром `/g` и вывод присвоить в переменную. Как - описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1136960/1597497)

Comment: Выдает {app}. Но вижу ключ не правильный, нужно указать HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation, но какой там параметр смотреть?

Comment: http://windata.ru/windows-xp/faq-xp/pokazhite-mne-dannye-o-chasovom-poyase-v-windows-xp/

Comment: Спасибо. Буду изучать.

Answer (score 0):

После поиска и изучения материала получился такой код (может кому-то пригодится):

```
function GetGMT(): string;
var
  ZoneName, gmt: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation', 'TimeZoneKeyName', ZoneName);
  if ZoneName <> '' then
    if RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\'+ZoneName) then
      if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\'+ZoneName, 'Display', gmt) then
        if gmt <> '' then Result := gmt;
end;
```